# Stores millions of daily IP address logs

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-structures

We have one click tracking system where i am tracking IP address of each request.

Each day we are getting millions of hits.

And for each request and storing IP address as 1 row in MySQL

We also need daily stats top 10 IP address hits.

This i am getting with MySQL but our problem is that database is getting 2 heavy and taking big space.

What i am looking for the good "data structure" where i can store this IP address in efficient way?

currently i am storing every hits as row if i'll select good data structure then my problem will solve

I am not want to run complex queries but top 10 per day, top 10 per ip address per week.

and must save the storage space

Comment: For how long are you storing the access log? Just one day for the stats, or keeping for good?

Comment: try upgrading to paid version or some other database vender.

Comment: long longs bigger like last 1 years more then that

Comment: Do you need to be able to do complex queries against the whole history, or would archiving it to file storage after say a month be a possibility?

Comment: Please show us the exact DDL. Are you using [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) type for IP addresses? Also, do you need to store each and every hit, or just aggregated hits over a period of time?

Comment: It sounds like your table is basically two columns: the IP and the request-time?

If a day is the lowest level of detail, you could make this three columns: the IP, the Date and a Request Count. Alternatively, you could have a history table where you summarize information every day.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need each ip access timestamp to be exactly to the second, you can partition each day into a series of time segments (maybe one segment every 10 or 5 minutes). Each datetime segment has an id in a time segments table. You can then create an id for every unique IP address in an ip table.

Then you have a join table where you associate IP addresses (foreign key) to time segments (foreign key) with a count (unsigned integer). So your core access row data is now reduced to simply 2 ids and 1 unsigned integer (and most importantly, no strings).

So when you receive a request from an IP, you determine the current time segment, and create a row for a new time segment if that time segment does not exist. If the current time segment has no association with the IP, create a new row with count being 1. If there is a row for this time segment and IP, increment the count.

By normalizing the data/tables this way, and reducing accuracy slightly, you achieve a form of information compression. Play around with time segment intervals to find the best trade off. E.g. if you dont need minutes or even hours granularity of querying, you could just make your time segment one day long.

**Update:**

Right, so everything above is to compress multiple hits from the same IP address.This obviously is more effective the more repetitive hits you get compared to unique hits. And is completely irrelevant if you only care about unique hits.

There are ways to compress IPv4 addresses into an unsigned int (32 bits). just bit shift each of the `a.b.c.d` parts into bytes `0xff000000`, `0x00ff0000`, `0x0000ff00`, `0x000000ff` respectively.

This way, you use 4 bytes per IP instead of a string; at which point there is no use in storing a foreign key (which takes at least 4 bytes anyway).  So you can just have a single denormalized table with fields: (IPv4 as an encoded unsigned int, datetime/timestamp as a 4 byte int). You could potentially replace the datetime with a day and a count, depending on if multiple hits count to you. If multiple hits dont count, you could really just get away with an int for IP and an int for date.

An even further option if day-granulartiy is that lowest that you need: you can clear this IP db table at the end of each day and store the results of your aggregate queries only in the database. The rest of the data can be archived and removed from the IP db table on a daily basis. This means that your table only needs to be one field: the encoded IP as an unsigned int. At this point the problem simply becomes building a large unique set of ints on a daily basis.

You can also flatten/denormalize the time (or time segment) into an int (or even smaller) as well depending on how frequent/granular you want to record time, and if you are choosing to aggregate/archive/clear the IP db table on a regular basis.

Another way to store multiple IP addresses in a compressed way is to use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure, however it does not map directly to database storage (as compared to an in-memory data structure). One way to store tree structures (such as a trie) via SQL is using the [Materialized Path](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-9902) method - however, this method does not achieve good data compression, and the query overhead might not be worth it.

Comment: For a BigData issue (and as here with low data complexity and relations) I would never continue down an RDBMS-based architecture. But yes. It IS perhaps possible to tweak and twiddle MySQL just enough to get by.

Comment: @tbsalling, yes, but the point is, its no longer "BigData" if you are able to compress the data to a tiny fraction of its original size, especially if it is orders of magnitude smaller. In fact, if you can compress it down to a much much smaller size, then it can save not only a misguided shift in technology stack, but it can save a lot of money and power, and perhaps be even faster. Throwing buzzwords at a problem is a really brute force way of solving a problem.

Comment: @tbsalling furthermore, my solution is a form of lossy compression and data normalization, not just merely "tweaking" and "twiddling", nor has it got anything to do with MySQL or even RDBMS's in particular. In fact you could, and probably should do similar optimizations on top of a NoSQL representation as well. Its these kind of "tweaks" and "twiddles" that help seperate the top companies from others when competing on certain performance and cost metrics. Squeezing more out of what resources you have is a cornerstone of good software engineering; throwing trending tech at a problem is naive.

Comment: but still this solution don't save the storage space

Answer (score -1):

If you can change database away from RDBMS technology like MySQL, then you should definitely have a look at NoSQL databases such as e.g. **CouchDB**, **Cassandra**, or **RIAK**.

These will scale to your needs - but work in a quite different way from SQL-databases - so expect some learning curve.

I can recommend to have a look at the book "[7 databases in 7 weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/rwdata/seven-databases-in-seven-weeks)" for a crash start.

Comment: Might as well suggest to try resetting the computer/server. You do not explain at all how NoSQL will help this particular situation

Comment: Well, I did point the asker in a useful direction. Without knowing whether NoSQL is at all an option for him it hardly makes sense to post a wall of text explaining how NoSQL would work for him. SO is a nice place to ask - but a hostile place to answer!

Comment: hardly. The point is that the OP is asking a question about information compression in RDBMSs, and there are immediate and obvious solutions within that space (MySQL). It's like asking about the best way to read a file in C++ and someone says try Python instead. Not particularly useful to list out a bunch of related technologies, especially without investing any effort to even hint at how they might help.

Comment: I cannot read out of the original question, that MySQL is a fixed part of the solution. The OP doesn't even carry the MySQL tag. No further comments.

Comment: It doesnt change the fact that you do not even hint at how your alternative dbms's will help the OP solve the performance/memory/scaling problem. You could easily just copy paste this response into every question about RDBMS's. "Hey, just try another DBMS technology, maybe it will be more performant. GOOD LUCK!"